# ¿Cómo hacer que una lista expandida se oculte al expandir otra lista?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una lista de acordeón

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordionMenu");
var activeItem = document.querySelector(".accordionMenu")

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("activeItem");
      activeItem.style.maxHeight = null;
      activeItem = this;
      let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
    });
}
```

```css
.panelItem {
    padding: 0 18px;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.accordionMenu {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordionMenuList">
  <p class="subtitle accordionMenu"><strong>Abc</strong></p>
  <div class="panelItem">
    <p><a href="/docs/en/abc/" class="white noUnderline">Introduction</a></p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="accordionMenuList">
  <p class="subtitle accordionMenu"><strong>Abc</strong></p>
  <div class="panelItem">
    <p><a href="/docs/en/abc/" class="white noUnderline">Introduction</a></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Hace básicamente cambiar el `maxHeight` al elemento clickeado y si está expandido quitarle el `maxHeight` para que se oculte

Funciona, el problema, es que quiero que si está desplegada una lista, al presionar otra se oculte la que está desplegada (si es que la hay)

Intenté definir una variable, como se puede ver `activeItem` y hacer `activeItem.style.maxHeight = null`, es decir quitar el `maxHeight` para que se oculte, pero no funciona

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes definir la variable dentro de la función, para que se actualice cada vez que se hace clic en algún elemento.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.accordionMenu').forEach(acc => {
    acc.addEventListener('click', e => {
        // Asegurar que el elemento es <p> y no <strong>
        let target = e.target.closest('.accordionMenu') || e.target;
        let panel = target.nextElementSibling;
        // Obtener elemento activo actual
        let act = document.querySelector('.accordionMenu.activeItem');
        // Solo si hay un elemento activo
        if(act) {
            // Eliminar clase al elemento activo actual
            act.classList.remove('activeItem');
            // Ocultar panel activo
            act.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = 0;
        }
        // Si el elemento activo recibió clic, solo se oculta, no se activa nuevamente
        if(act != target) {
            // Activar elemento que recibió el clic
            target.classList.add('activeItem');
            // Mostrar panel
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + 'px';
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.accordionMenu {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.accordionMenu ~ .panelItem {
    padding: 0 18px;
    max-height:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordionMenuList">
  <p class="subtitle accordionMenu"><strong>Abc</strong></p>
  <div class="panelItem">
    <p><a href="/docs/en/abc/" class="white noUnderline">Introduction</a></p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="accordionMenuList">
  <p class="subtitle accordionMenu"><strong>Abc</strong></p>
  <div class="panelItem">
    <p><a href="/docs/en/abc/" class="white noUnderline">Introduction</a></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Notas:**

1. Intenté hacerlo solo con CSS, pero solo funciona bien cuando hay medidas específicas, de lo contrario, la animación hace un efecto raro
2. Prefiero usar `querySelectorAll()` que `getElementByClassName()` porque devuelve una lista de nodos que se puede recorrer con `forEach()`; me parece que el código queda más fácil de entender, aunque puede ser cuestión de preferencias
3. Trato de evitar `this` porque puede variar, dependiendo del contexto y puedes obtener datos desde el evento